# Interesting weekly leagues... part of the Users redesign?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

Maybe this is due to changing things ahead of the Users page redesign, but currently the [Weekly SO League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) is claiming that [anon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/anon) gained 89,657 rep yesterday. That seems unlikely to me.

The first few users on the list seem to be wrong... the first more realistic one is Commonsware which the league claims to have gained 305 yesterday, although my [rep tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=115145&sf=&su=&meta=&mode=yesterday&showflair=true) reckons he got 320.

Is this all explained by oddness in the global rep recalc, or is something odder going on?

Comment: we were talking about this earlier, its an accidental side-effect of the recalc. peace and your well deserved #1 ranking will be restored in the next day or two.

Comment: @waffles: I'm rarely top ranked in the week, to be honest. Just interested to see the oddities here :)

Comment: Also "anon" hasn't visited since August 2010. His reputation graph seems fine however.

Comment: Neil's digital ghost, still kicking ass on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just finished a complete recalc of the rep leagues.  Take a look and see if anything looks wrong.

Comment: From the [all time leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta-stackoverflow), everyone on Meta Stack Overflow seems to be around 2k off from their values post-recalc. Not a consistent amount, either, as cletus is 4 places below where he is according to the users list. Stack Overflow is looking accurate, though, giving leverage for today's not-yet-recorded activity.

Comment: @Grace hm looks like meta.SO might not have been updated...looking into it

Comment: The SO weekly looks right, yes :)

Comment: @Grace MSO should be fixed now...I used the wrong settings (+5 for question upvote instead of +10)

Comment: Looks indeed to be fixed now. Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 6):

That person was a user who decided to leave and asked his account to be deleted. However, since he had too many posts it couldn't be deleted the normal way, so they simply anonimized it and set his denormalized reputation to 1.

When the rep recalc kicked in it reset his reputation to what it should actually be, and this caused him to be on the top of the rep leagues.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed you got 4895 reps (rough calculations) in previous five days through stackoverflow api.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/22656/reputation?fromdate=0&page=1&pagesize=100

Comment: That's very odd - for example, the "Best Java IDE for Visual Studio fan?" entry, which shows +77/-8, whereas I can just see at a total of -2 for that post in recent times.